# Rails - touching parent of a parent

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Three models: Post, Comment, Rating.

**Post**

```
class Post < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :comments
    has_many :ratings, through: :comments
end
```

**Comment**

```
class Comment < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :post
    has_one :rating
end
```

**Rating**

```
class Rating < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :comment
end
```

I want to be able to do call a method on Post model (to for example calculate `mean_rating`) when the `Rating` record gets added or removed to my database.

I am able to to this with calling the post model method inside rating model `after_create` and `after_destroy` but I am wondering if there is a way to update Post model using dependent or any other methods?

Any ideas?

Answer (score -1):

You could create a method in your Post model:

```
class Post < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :comments
  has_many :ratings, through: :comments

  def average_rating
    ratings.average(:note)
  end
end
```

And call it on your instances:

```
post = Post.last
post.average_rating
```